# unable to Access a Docker Container from Another Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-network

I want to access the `lowerquality/gentle` container into my Django container. when I run the docker-compose up command I cannot access the gentle container by `localhost:49153` I can access the localhost:49153 through my laptop but cannot access it inside the Django container.

Docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    # command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
  db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

  # redis:
  #   image: redis
  #   ports:
  #     - '6379:6379'
  #   expose:
  #     - 6379

  djangoq:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/media
    depends_on:
      # - redis
      - web
      - gentle
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    
  gentle:
    restart: always
    image: lowerquality/gentle
    ports:
      - '49153:8765'
    expose:
      - 49153

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Error accessing the gentle container inside the django container.

[image: docker container error]

I did change the URL path to `localhost:49153` and `gentle:49153` could not access

accessing from my laptop is working using `localhost:49153`

[image: accessing container from laptop]

I did try to access using `localhost:49153`, `gentle:49153` and `gentle`

How can I access gentle container inside Django container?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  What is the actual error?  In Docker, `localhost` almost always refers to the current container and not another, so you could get an error if `localhost:49153` is trying to talk to that port in the application container.  It also would help clarify the question to reduce the Compose file to a [mcve] and remove unnecessary containers and options.

Answer (score 1):

Containers can only communicate with each other if they share a network. Containers that don't share a network cannot talk with one another. That's one of the isolation features provided by Docker.

[Read his link for more information.](https://maximorlov.com/4-reasons-why-your-docker-containers-cant-talk-to-each-other/)

You could add a network at the end of your docker-compose file.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: <your_network_name>
```

**Note:** You should create the network first.

```bash
docker network create <your_network_name>
```

After these changes, you can use a container or hostname of your container to connect to another container in the network.

**Note:** run `docker ps` to see container names.

Comment: then how come the postgres database name db is attach to django? after applying the changes the database stop working .

Comment: you should change host_name in django .env to your container name not localhost

Comment: [Compose provides a network named `default` automatically.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)  So long as there are no `networks:` blocks at all in the file, you're using this `default` network and containers can communicate using it.

Comment: did not work. did try same error.

Comment: could I see your new error? @MuhammadKamal

Comment: Thanks, David for your comment. but sometimes I defined my container in separate docker-compose files so I should reference the same network to know each other. @DavidMaze

Comment: You can [reconfigure the `default` network](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) if you need to, including attaching it to an existing network.

Answer (score 1):

The correct connection string is `gentle:8765`